# VPS Upload speeds < 1 mbps

Tags: centos, vps, upload

I have a Centos server running in eastern canada.  When I use speedtest.net and connect to a server up there, I get around 30 down.  If I use speedtest-cli and connect to a server down here I get about 40 up.  However, when I download directly from my server, I get around 100kbps.  Webdav crashes because its so slow.  ethtool and miitool show no results, probably because its a VPS.
What could I use to find the problem?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Webdav is almost always very slow.  Try transfering some files by regular http, ftp and/or scp and see if that is faster.  If it is, its a software issue with whatever you use for webdav.

Its also possible the network between you and speedtest.net is great, and between the server and speedtest.net is great, but the network path between you and the vps is slower.

Comment: I've tried several different ways of downloading, but they're all pretty close to the same speed.
Could it cause that big of a difference?

Answer (score 1):

On the website of your VPS Provider, you will (likely) see which Internet speed and bandwidth you have got.

If you have used all your bandwidth, your VPS might have been throttled.

The VPS or the VPS Provider might be under a DDoS Attack, this can lower your speed or even block the connection.

Or the VPS is very far away from your location, this can cause high latency and lower your speed.

Or (very unlikely) you have been hacked and your server is being used in a bot net.

I recommend contacting your VPS Provider.